# arecord / aplay stop after a while

Tags: alsa

I am looping the "PCM audio in" to the "PCM audio out" on a Sound Blaster USB card using the following command:

```
arecord -q -f S16_LE -r 48000 -c 2 -D dsnoop:HD | aplay -q -D plughw:HD
```

It works fine, but only for about three hours.
The command is in a while loop which restarts it when it stops and also records the time at which the command is restarted.
It has run for the following lengths of time:

h  m  s

03:06:48

03:06:27

03:06:27

03:06:26

About 11,187 seconds, give or take.
These seem too similar to be the result of a random fault.
The man pages for aplay and a record say that a duration of 0 means infinity.

Any suggestions as to why it stops reliably after 3hr 6min and 27seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.wav files have a 2 GB size limit.

Use `-t raw` instead:

```
arecord -q -f dat -t raw -D dsnoop:HD | aplay -q -f dat -t raw -D plughw:HD
```

Comment: That fixed it. Its been going for over 5 hours now. Although 11187 sec * 48000 s/sec * 2 channels * 2 bytes/sample = 2.147 MB so out by 2 somewhere. On re-reading the man page perhaps --max-file-time may also have worked. Well spotted, many thanks.